# solving a variable number of equations

Tags: equation-solving

So I have a set of N equations (where N is something I would like to vary):

$W_N(z)-1 = zW_{N-1}(z)$

$W_i(z) -2 = z (W_{i+1}(z)+W_{i-1}(z)))$ for $i=1,...N-1$

$W_0(z) -1 = z W_1(z)$

Is there a way I can ask Mathematica to try and solve these with N as a parameter?

Comment: `RSolve[]`, maybe?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Michael E2

```
eqns = {w[nmax, z] - 1 == z*w[nmax - 1, z],
   w[n, z] - 2 == z (w[n + 1, z] + w[n - 1, z]),
   w[0, z] - 1 == z*w[1, z]};
```

Assuming `z > 0`

```
soln = RSolve[eqns, w, {n, z}][[1]] //
  Simplify[#, z > 0] &

(*  {w -> Function[{n, z}, 
       -((2^nmax*(-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 
                        1/z)^n - 2^(1 + n)*
                   (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax - 2^nmax*
                   (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     n + (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 
                        1/z)^nmax*
                   (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     n + 2^(1 + n)*
                   (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax - 
                 (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^n*
                   (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax - 2^nmax*
                   Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                   (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     n*z + 2^(1 + n)*
                   Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                   (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax*z - 2^nmax*
                   Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                   (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^n*
                   z - Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                   (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax*(Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 
                        1/z)^n*z + 2^(1 + n)*
                   Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                   (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax*z - Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                   (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     n*(Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 
                        1/z)^nmax*z + 2^(2 + n)*
                   (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax*z^2 - 2^(2 + n)*
                   (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                     nmax*z^2)/2^n/((-1 + 2*z)*
               (-(-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                      nmax + 
                  (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                    nmax + Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                    (-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                      nmax*z + Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2]*
                    (Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                      nmax*z + 
                  2*(-Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                      nmax*z^2 - 
                  2*(Sqrt[-4 + 1/z^2] + 1/z)^
                      nmax*z^2)))]}  *)
```

Verifying that `soln` satisfies `eqns`

```
eqns /. soln // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```